# Facebook "All Mutual Friends API(me/friends)" returning friends data array blank

Tags: android, facebook-graph-api, facebook-android-sdk

Added permission "user_friends". Before it was working fine. i wonder it stopped working.

Comment: post your code.

Comment: Can you describe the behaviour before it stopped working? It might be useful

Comment: There was two of friends who were using same app and was available to my friend list. when more friends started using same app was not in me/friends array. Then i also ask them(who were visible in friends array) to remove from facebook setting to test again they registered with app. Now Array is blank none of friend is available.

Comment: Then they most likely did not grant the `user_friends` permission on their end, when they re-authorized the app.

Answer (score 0):

Solved problem by removing package name from `developer.facebook.com` and adding it again..